# Error: Inline JavaScript is not enabled - Gatsby with gatsby-plugin-less and gatsby-plugin-antd

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

Description:
I'm encountering an error while using Gatsby along with `gatsby-plugin-less` and `gatsby-plugin-antd`. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK.DEVELOP

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-less/node_module
s/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


// https://github.com/ant-design/ant-motion/issues/44
.bezierEasingMixin();
^
Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?
      Error in /Users/shubhambelwal/Documents/xxx/nod
e_modules/antd/es/style/color/bezierEasing.less (line 110, column 0)
```

Here is my Gatsby configuration in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-antd',
    'gatsby-plugin-less',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-antd',
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        style: true,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-less',
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
  ]
}
```

I have the following dependencies installed:

```
gatsby-plugin-less@^6.20.0
less@^2.7.1
less-loader@^3.0.0
gatsby-plugin-antd@^2.2.0
antd@^3.26.11
```

Despite configuring the plugins with `javascriptEnabled: true`, I'm still encountering this error. How can I resolve this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!